# Flutter image animate bigger and smaller

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to make a simple recurring animation to an image. It should keep animating until the user closes the screen. What I want it that the image slowly gets bigger and then smaller.

I've checked the animatedContainer, but that doesn't seem to do this dynamically. Here is the code I used with AnimatedContainer:

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
  increaseSize(widget.seconds);
  super.didChangeDependencies();
}

void increaseSize(int toSize) {
for (i = 0; i > toSize; i++) {
  setState(() {
    _width += i;
    _height += i;
  });
 }
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
  // Use the properties stored in the State class.
  width: _width,
  height: _height,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: _color,
    borderRadius: _borderRadius,
  ),
   // Define how long the animation should take.
   duration: Duration(seconds: 30),
   // Provide an optional curve to make the animation feel smoother.
   curve: Curves.easeInOutBack,
   );
  ;
}
```

Has anyone come across this before, any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Could you share the code you tried using the animatedContainer?

Comment: @Er1 yes sure please see the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

It's an example of a container which grows and shrinks from 50 to 100 and back to 50.

```dart
class SizeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int seconds;

  const SizeWidget({this.seconds = 3});

  @override
  _SizeWidgetState createState() => _SizeWidgetState();
}

class _SizeWidgetState extends State<SizeWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _sizeAnimation;

  bool reverse = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: widget.seconds))
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          _animationController.repeat(reverse: !reverse);
          reverse = !reverse;
        }
      });

    _sizeAnimation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 50.0, end: 100.0).animate(_animationController);
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _sizeAnimation,
      builder: (context, child) => Container(
        width: _sizeAnimation.value,
        height: _sizeAnimation.value,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a [TweenSequence](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/TweenSequence-class.html) and tell the animation controller to repeat itself:

```dart
class SizeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int seconds;

  const SizeWidget({this.seconds = 3});

  @override
  _SizeWidgetState createState() => _SizeWidgetState();
}

class _SizeWidgetState extends State<SizeWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _sizeAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: widget.seconds));

    _sizeAnimation = TweenSequence<double>(
      [
        TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(
            begin: 50,
            end: 100,
          ),
          weight: 50,
        ),
        TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(
            begin: 100,
            end: 50,
          ),
          weight: 50,
        ),
      ],
    ).animate(_animationController);
    _animationController.repeat(reverse: true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _sizeAnimation,
      builder: (context, child) => Container(
        width: _sizeAnimation.value,
        height: _sizeAnimation.value,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```